# What is a 'GREF'?

Tags: android

In [this bug report on Xamarin/Android](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=25443) they are talking about GREF and GREF counts.

What is a GREF?

Comment: What about searching for the answer first yourself?

Comment: Google did not return any results when searching for 'gref'. Indeed, 'xamarin gref' turns up more interesting stuff, although still no definition.

Comment: It's worth noting that this question is now the first google result for the search term "android gref". Sad to see the question voted to the ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used in C# using Xamarin and is short for `Global Reference`.